# Issue with SQL INSERT Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-insert

I'm reaching out for some help on this trigger I'm trying to get working.

Basically this is what I'm trying to do.
We have DMS software that writes to a Database and on a particular `INSERT` value I want the trigger to fire.

This is an example of an `INSERT` statement that will get processed.

```
INSERT INTO DOCSADM.ACTIVITYLOG (CR_IN_USE,ACTIVITY_DESC,BILLED_ON,BILLABLE,PAGES,KEYSTROKES,
TYPE_TIME,ELAPSED_TIME,TYPIST,AUTHOR,START_DATE,ACTIVITY_TYPE,REF_DOCUMENT,REF_LIBRARY,APPLICATION,VERSION_LABEL,DOCNUMBER,SYSTEM_ID) 
VALUES ('','DOCSFusion','1753-01-01','',0,0,0,0,1920,1920,'2020-08-26T10:17:56',**115**,0,-1,1173,'',75,3252)
```

but I only want the trigger to fire when we see a value of 115 for the bold section in the `INSERT` statement (the Activity_type value).

For all other values that re not 115 I don't want to do anything.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BW_TRIGGER
   ON  DOCSADM.ACTIVITYLOG
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
       -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
       -- interfering with SELECT statements.
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

--Declare some variable and set it as a value of 115.
--Example:
DECLARE @AlogType int = (SELECT I.ACTIVITY_TYPE FROM DOCSADM.ACTIVITYLOG A, INSERTED I) --This is the value you are looking for regarding the DM client/Matter actitivty type.
DECLARE @AlogDesc varchar(32) = (Select i.ACTIVITY_DESC from docsadm.ACTIVITYLOG A, INSERTED I) 

--Next, you should have a fork or path in your trigger to determine how it proceeds.
--Path 1: The @AlogType value matches the inserted value so you want to process the rest of the trigger.  Example path – “ProcessTrigger:”
--Path 2: The @AlogType value does NOT match the inserted value, you want to exit the trigger.  Example Path – “ExitTrigger:”


IF @AlogType <> 115 
GOTO TriggerExit;
ELSE

Begin

/*Create first temp table to collect insert values*/  --This table will have the SysID Value and the corresponding docnumber for the items you want.  
--You can add whatever other values you think you need.
CREATE TABLE #TempSet1
(
AlogsysID INT,
Docnum INT,
AlogDate Varchar(64),
AlogTypist INT,
AlogAuthor INT,
AlogDesc varchar(32),
ALOGVER varchar(10),
ALOG_MATTER INT
)


INSERT INTO #TempSet1 (AlogsysID,Docnum,AlogDate,AlogTypist,AlogAuthor, ALOG_MATTER)
--SELECT  You SELECT STATEMENT WILL GO HERE MODIFIED TO POPULATE THE TABLE WITH THE DOCNUMBERS YOU WANT!!
select top 1 System_id, docnumber, LAST_ACCESS_DATE, TYPIST, AUTHOR, MATTER from docsadm.PROFILE where EXISTS  (SELECT CLIENT.SYSTEM_ID FROM DOCSADM.CLIENT  INNER JOIN DOCSADM.MATTER ON MATTER.CLIENT_ID = CLIENT.SYSTEM_ID  
WHERE MATTER.SYSTEM_ID =@AlogDesc  OR  INH_LUP_SEC_FROM IS NULL OR INH_LUP_SEC_FROM = 0) AND MATTER=@AlogDesc


/*Set variable @SysID as the LASTKEY value -1.  This will be used to set the SysID column on the #TempSet table*/ 
--DECLARE @SysID INT = (SELECT LASTKEY FROM DOCSADM.SEQ_SYSTEMKEY) -1;

/*Set the SysID value for every row on the #TempSet1 table as the @SysID variable +1*/
--UPDATE #TempSet1
--SET @SysID = AlogsysID = @SysID + 1

--Your #TempSet should now be set with ALL of the System_IDs and Docnumbers necessary for your insert!!!!—

--Verify this by doing a select against the #TempSet1 Table
SELECT * FROM #TempSet1;

--Next you need to set the SystemID to the correct value for future processing.  To do this, we need to get a total count from the #TempSet table.
/*Set a variable to update the NEXTKEY value on the DOCSADM.SEQ_SYSTEMKEY table.  The NEXTKEY value is used for the SYSTEM_ID field*/
--DECLARE @SeqUpdateCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempSet1);

/*Update the LASTKEY Value on the SEQ_SYSTEMKEY table to the next available value for DM.*/
--UPDATE DOCSADM.SEQ_SYSTEMKEY SET LASTKEY = LASTKEY+@SeqUpdateCount

--If you have all the values you need in your temp table, you can now insert them into the ACTIVITYLOG table.

--INSERT INTO DOCSADM.ACTIVITY 
--(SYSTEM_ID, DOCNUMBER, START_DATE, version, EXT,)
--SELECT 
--AlogSysID,Docnum,GETUTCDATE(),BLAH, BLAH
--FROM #TableSet1


INSERT INTO DOCSADM.ACTIVITYLOG 
(SYSTEM_ID,
DOCNUMBER,
START_DATE,
TYPIST,
AUTHOR,
ACTIVITY_DESC,
VERSION_LABEL, 
ACTIVITY_TYPE)
SELECT 
AlogsysID, Docnum,AlogDate,AlogTypist, AlogAuthor, ALOG_MATTER, '',115
FROM #TempSet1;

--Now you need to Drop the Temp Table
DROP TABLE #TempSet1

--Go to the other half of your path above to exit the trigger.

END


 TriggerExit:


END
Go
```

but when I try to run any `INSERT` statement on this table I get this error message. It doesn't matter if the activity_type has a value of 115 or not

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I know the issue is with this section of the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO #TempSet1 (AlogsysID,Docnum,AlogDate,AlogTypist,AlogAuthor, ALOG_MATTER)
--SELECT  You SELECT STATEMENT WILL GO HERE MODIFIED TO POPULATE THE TABLE WITH THE DOCNUMBERS YOU WANT!!
SELECT TOP 1 
System_id
, docnumber
, LAST_ACCESS_DATE
, TYPIST
, AUTHOR
, MATTER 
FROM docsadm.PROFILE 
WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT CLIENT.SYSTEM_ID 
               FROM DOCSADM.CLIENT  
               INNER JOIN DOCSADM.MATTER 
                     ON MATTER.CLIENT_ID = CLIENT.SYSTEM_ID  
               WHERE MATTER.SYSTEM_ID =@AlogDesc  
                     OR  INH_LUP_SEC_FROM IS NULL 
                     OR INH_LUP_SEC_FROM = 0)
      AND MATTER=@AlogDesc
```

It's the `SELECT` statement that is causing it to fail.
I know that this statement will bring back multiple rows but I only need the value from one of them so I can use this value for my `INSERT`.  I though having the "select top 1" would do this for me but it's not working like I think it should. What am I missing?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I would guess SQL Server.

Comment: Im using SQL server 2017

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I would say your problem is here:

```
DECLARE @AlogType int = (SELECT I.ACTIVITY_TYPE FROM DOCSADM.ACTIVITYLOG A, INSERTED I) --This is the value you are looking for regarding the DM client/Matter actitivty type.
DECLARE @AlogDesc varchar(32) = (Select i.ACTIVITY_DESC from docsadm.ACTIVITYLOG A, INSERTED I)
```

How are `ACTIVITYLOG` and `INSERTED` joined in the above ? without a where it would be a `CROSS JOIN`. Why do you even drag `ACTIVITYLOG` into it, you can simply use `INSERTED`. Also please try to stop using implicit joins ( I can see that later down the script you use the proper, more verbose join syntax)

TRY:

```
DECLARE @AlogType int = (SELECT I.ACTIVITY_TYPE FROM INSERTED I) --This is the value you are looking for regarding the DM client/Matter actitivty type.
DECLARE @AlogDesc varchar(32) = (Select i.ACTIVITY_DESC from INSERTED I)
```

Be careful that this will work with single inserts only. When you do batched inserts the `INSERTED` is a table containing multiple rows and you will run into issues again.

Comment: thanks for the reply. im not sure i follow you on this question:"How are ACTIVITYLOG and INSERTED joined in the above"   the "inserted" section is not a table. i thought this was used to grab the "insert" statement value that is being ran. we do have multiple insert statements that fire for every new doc being created so we would see like 3 or 4 insert statements that get created into the activitylog table that have different activity type values. but i only want to grab the values that have 115. all other values i dont need and the trigger can exit.

Comment: i re-read your comment. these insert statements do get ran in a batched. So is there a away to avoid this issue from happening?  the main issue is a bug in our software for a security issue and this will be a workaround until we can fix this in code.

Comment: @BWHITE1 You are NOT grabbing the "insert" statement. Your trigger needs to "know" which rows were inserted and those rows are in the inserted virtual table - every column. So there is no need to join back to the actual table (even if the join were correctly formed). And that statement, as suggested, is based on a false assumption. The inserted table can contain zero (yes) to any number of rows - don't assume there will always be a single row. And stop using the mostly useless <select into #temp ... select * from #temp> pattern without any reason for doing so.

Comment: so removing the "FROM DOCSADM.ACTIVITYLOG A" from the declare made the error go away but now im not seeing my new insert value being populated. Does any one know the best way to see what the trigger is doing when it fires?

Comment: use a non-temp table so you can see what values get populated. That way it will be easier for you to debug the logic